# Sum of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How can I find the sum of the convergent series

Sum from n=1 to infinite of $\frac {e^i}{3^{(i-2)}}$. I know it can be split into Sum of (e.3)^1 + sum of e^i/3^-2. But with this I have e^i which is divergent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by $n$ you meant $i$. In that case, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^i}{3^{i-2}} &= 3^2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^i \\
& = 9\left(\frac{\frac{e}{3}}{1 - \frac{e}{3}}\right) \\
& = \frac{9e}{3 - e}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^i}{3^{i-2}} = 3^2 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{e}{3} \right)^i$$
and the last is a geometric series with the ratio $<1$.